# Oracle Table Function from CTE

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, common-table-expression

I'd like to create a table function in oracle from the following query:

```
 WITH A AS (
    SELECT * FROM PART_TABLE WHERE PART_NO LIKE part_num
 )
SELECT * FROM A;
```

'part_num' being a parameter passed into the function. I am having trouble with the syntax. This is what I have tried:

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION part_test_f(search_part IN varchar2)
RETURN part_test_t PIPELINED 
AS 

    rec PART_TEST;

    CURSOR cur(part_num) IS 
         WITH A AS (
            SELECT * FROM PART_TABLE WHERE PART_NO LIKE part_num
         )
        SELECT * FROM A;
BEGIN
        FOR record IN cur(search_part) LOOP
        rec := PART_TEST(record);
        pipe row(rec);
        END LOOP;
return;
END;
```

I have created the types for the table and the rows. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I have given it another go. The declaration now looks like:

```
    create or replace FUNCTION part_test_f(search_part IN varchar2)
RETURN part_test_t PIPELINED
AS

    rec PART_TEST;

    CURSOR cur(part_num varchar2) RETURN PART_TEST IS
         WITH A AS (
            SELECT * FROM F6RD_PART WHERE PART_NO LIKE part_num
         )
        SELECT * FROM A;
BEGIN
        FOR rec IN cur(search_part) LOOP
        pipe row(rec);
        END LOOP;
return;
END;
```

Now I receive an 'No more data to read from socket' error

Comment: What isn’t working? There isn’t much point using a CTE if all you do with it is `select *`. Also, you might construct your `part_test` object within the cursor and save a processing step.

Comment: The point of the query is to determine correct syntax. In actuality I have a much more complicated CTE; I am just trying to figure out the corrrect syntax to output a table from a function that is wrapping a CTE. This is as far as I have gotten using the other resources I was able to find on the internet.

Comment: Right now my result is that the function is an invalid state. The user_errors table states that 'PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   in out <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   ... long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary
   national character nchar' on line 7, position 21

Comment: I think the compilation error is telling you the cursor parameter is missing a datatype. (By the way even SQL\*Plus has a `show errors` command - do you not have any development tools?) But my point goes for any CTE however simple or complex.

Comment: Using Dbeaver. Not familiar with SQL*Plus; I'm pretty new at this. Should I add a `varchar2` to the part_num portion of the cursor declaration?

Comment: Your cursor cannot return a `PART_TEST` record because it returns a record based on the query `... SELECT * FROM A`. Note: it doesn't matter if the columns returned by the query happen to match the components of the record type, the compiler can't assume they map exactly. You have to map it to a record in your loop.

Comment: That is correct, thank you Jeffrey Kemp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While dealing with `Objects` you be extra cautious while making `select`. There were errors in your code which were resulting in issues. Also am not very sure if direct assignment done below is actually allowed:

`rec := PART_TEST(record);`

However I propose 2 solutions here. First with `Pipeline` and other without it. See below:

***--Table and Objects Preparation***

```
CREATE TABLE part_table (
    part_no   NUMBER,
    col1      NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO PART_TABLE VALUES(1,11);
INSERT INTO PART_TABLE VALUES(1,33);
INSERT INTO PART_TABLE VALUES(2,22);

SELECT * FROM PART_TABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE part_test IS OBJECT (
    part_no   NUMBER,
    col1      NUMBER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE part_test_t IS  TABLE OF part_test;
/
```

***--Function with Pipeline***

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION part_test_f(search_part IN number)
RETURN part_test_t PIPELINED 
AS 

 rec part_test; --<--Variable of type Object since we want to piperow.

 CURSOR cur(part_num number) IS 
      WITH A AS 
      (       --Make sure you cast your select statement of object type    
              SELECT part_test(PART_NO,col1) FROM PART_TABLE WHERE PART_NO LIKE part_num
       )
       SELECT * FROM A;        
BEGIN        
   OPEN cur(search_part) ;
    LOOP
      Fetch cur into rec;    --<-- Note here am not using `Bulk Collect` even though its being a collection since we are `piping` the rows.    
      exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
       pipe row(rec);         
    END LOOP;
RETURN ;
END;
/
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE (PART_TEST_F(1));

     PART_NO       COL1
    ---------- ----------
      1            11
      1            33
```

***--Without Pipeline***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION part_test_f (search_part IN NUMBER) 
RETURN part_test_t 
 AS
    rec   part_test_t;
    CURSOR cur ( part_num NUMBER) IS 
    WITH a AS 
    ( SELECT part_test( part_no,col1 )
       FROM part_table
       WHERE part_no LIKE part_num       
    ) 
    SELECT *  FROM a;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur(search_part);
    LOOP
        FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO rec;
        EXIT WHEN cur%notfound;      
    END LOOP;
    RETURN rec;
END;
/
```

Result:

```
SQL> Select * from table (part_test_f(1));

   PART_NO       COL1
---------- ----------
         1         11
         1         33
```

Choose whichever suits you but we all know the advantages of using `Pipeline` functions hence that would be best suited.

Comment: This is the comprehensive answer I was looking for. Thanks