# Problem in SQL query(Expected output not coming)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new to Mysql.I have a table Student with following atttributes of column:

```
Result as 'F for fail','P' for pass,
Four department MECH,CSE ECE,EEE,
YEAR as 1,2,3,4 
Mark from 1 to 100
Name as name of student
and first column is auto generated Id
```

[image]

My expected output is:

[image]

I tried to get this output using:

```
 SELECT t1.* FROM(SELECT YEAR,
CASE WHEN DEPT='CSE' THEN COUNT(RESULT) ELSE NULL END CSE ,
CASE WHEN DEPT='ECE' THEN COUNT(RESULT) ELSE NULL END ECE,
CASE WHEN DEPT='MECH' THEN COUNT(RESULT) ELSE NULL END MECh, 
CASE WHEN DEPT='EEE' THEN COUNT(RESULT) ELSE NULL END EEE,
 CASE WHEN DEPT='CIE' THEN COUNT(RESULT) ELSE NULL END CIE
 FROM OT.STUDENT GROUP BY YEAR,DEPT,RESULT) t1
```

My output coming is:

[image]

I am stuck here.I have done group by but why 1,2,3,4 is coming repeatedly?The 1 is printed for 8times as there are just four years..I think I m wrong in my query.This is my output when i sorted ascending:

[image]

Comment: Tag properly!!!  If this is MySQL, why do I see Oracle tag on the question?

Comment: i am doing in toad oracle

Comment: But you said this is MySQL?

Comment: What happen if you remove `ELSE NULL`?

Comment: same result appeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation.  This looks like:

```
SELECT YEAR,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DEPT = 'CSE' AND RESULT = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CSE_pass,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DEPT = 'CSE' AND RESULT = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CSE_fail,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DEPT = 'ECE' AND RESULT = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ECE_pass,
       . . .
FROM OT.STUDENT
GROUP BY YEAR;
```

The `GROUP BY` keys define each row in the result set -- each combination of values is one row.  You want one row per year, so that should be the only column in the `GROUP BY`.