# CTE inside Table-valued function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression

I'm trying to write a Table-valued function in oracle, which contains a CTE.
I've been able to do it in SQL Server in this way:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[region_parents]
(   
    @regionId INT
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH cte AS
                        (
                          SELECT id, owner_region_id FROM regions WHERE id =  @regionId
 
                          UNION ALL
 
                          SELECT r.id, r.owner_region_id
                          FROM cte INNER JOIN 
                            regions r ON cte.owner_region_id = r.id
                        )

    SELECT id
    FROM cte
)
```

This is needed in order to call it in a cross apply:

```
SELECT *
FROM shops s
...
...
...

INNER JOIN locations l ON s.location_id = l.id
LEFT JOIN location_criteria lc ON lc.location_id = l.id

CROSS APPLY region_parents(l.region_id) r
```

In Oracle, I've tried to do it in this way, using User-Defined Datatypes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TABLE_RES_OBJ AS OBJECT (
     id                  NUMBER
);


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TABLE_RES AS TABLE OF TABLE_RES_OBJ;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION region_parents (regionId IN INTEGER)
RETURN TABLE_RES
IS
cteresult TABLE_RES;
BEGIN
    WITH cte(id, owner_region_id) AS
                        (
                          SELECT id AS id, owner_region_id AS owner_region_id FROM regions WHERE id = regionId
 
                          UNION ALL
 
                          SELECT r.id, r.owner_region_id
                          FROM cte INNER JOIN 
                            regions r ON cte.owner_region_id = r.id
                        )

    SELECT TABLE_RES(id)
    BULK COLLECT INTO cteresult
    FROM cte;
    RETURN cteresult;
END;
/
```

The problem is that I obtain the following error:

PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got NUMBER

I've also tried to achieve it in this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615259/oracle-table-function-from-cte), without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a simple distraction: "SELECT TABLE_RES(id)" should be "SELECT TABLE_RES_OBJ(id)".

Comment: Note that with a recent version of ORACLE, you can just write a SQL_MACRO, and using CONNECT BY for this simple use case makes the code even shorter:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION region_parents (regionId IN INTEGER)
RETURN VARCHAR2
SQL_MACRO
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN q'~SELECT id FROM regions START WITH id = regionId CONNECT BY owner_region_id = PRIOR id~' ;
END ;
no need to define TYPEs.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't anything to do with the CTE. You're trying to select a table object, not a simple object that is an element/row in that table. This:

```
    SELECT TABLE_RES(id)
    BULK COLLECT INTO cteresult
    FROM cte;
```

should be:

```
    SELECT TABLE_RES_OBJ(id)
    BULK COLLECT INTO cteresult
    FROM cte;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q34HDp7K)